Spring @Transactional isolation level
I want to clarify if I understood correctly how @Transactional works. I read about isolation levels in the postgreSQL documentation.
The database image that I used: postgres:16.4-alpine3.20
Spring boot version: 3.3.4
Full code

If the method has an annotation @Transaction(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED), then phantom reads are possible, but non-repeating reads are not possible. As far as I understand, this contradicts the postgres documentation (it says non-repeating reads are possible).

Tests:
...

void testNonRepeatableReadAndPhantomRead() throws InterruptedException {
 Book book = bookService.saveBook(new Book(null, "Book 1", null));
 Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> bookService.repeatingBookRead(List.of(1L, 1L, 2L)));
 thread1.start();
 Thread.sleep(200L);
 book.setTitle("Book 1 updated");
 book = bookRepository.save(book);
 log.info("Saved book: {}", book.getTitle());
 bookService.saveBook(new Book(null, "Book 2", null));
}

Service:
...

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
 public void repeatingBookRead(List<Long> bookIds) {
  long waitTime = 500L;
  bookIds.forEach(bookId -> oneBookRead(bookId, waitTime));
}


A little bit of context. There is a book, only 1 person can own the same book at the same time. If you write such a method:

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public boolean takeBook(Long personId, Long bookId) throws InterruptedException {
    Person person = personRepository.findById(personId).orElseThrow();
    Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId).orElseThrow();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if (person.getAge() > 18 && book.getOwner() == null) {
        book.setOwner(person);
        bookRepository.save(book);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

You will get undesirable behavior. Two people will be told that they have booked the same one. To avoid this behavior, you can set @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
@Transaction(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED) makes sense to use if you need to read data from the same database snapshot several times or when modifying multiple entities. Are there any other cases where it is necessary?

you are actually facing with lost update but not phantom read phenomenon (reproducing isolation level phenomena is actually "bit challenging"), which could be solved via explicit pessimistic or implicit optimistic lock or even tricky update statement like update book set owner = ? where id = ? and owner is null could help, and yes, switching to RR isolation level could help as well, however, in my opinion, switching to isolation level which is not widespread default for particular DB engine is always a poor idea.
